# Plotting Multiple Scales on the same plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib as plt
import datetime as date

start = date.datetime(2000,1,1)
end = date.datetime.today()
df = web.DataReader('fb', 'yahoo',start, end)
df2  = web.DataReader('f', 'yahoo',start, end)

ax = df.plot(y = 'Close')

df3 = df2.pct_change()
df3.plot(y = 'Close', ax=ax)
```

This code produces the following chart:

[image]

The orange line is of a plot where it is percentage change thus it is plotted as a horizontal line.

Is it possible to plot percentage change on the same plot where i have plotted another symbol against price. What i had in mind was so that on the right axis it would show the percentage and on the left it would be the price. Is it possible ? If so could you please show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little change : you need to use `plt.subplots()` as well as [twinx](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.twinx.html). This way, the x-axis will be duplicated from ax, and use the other side of the plot for the y-axis

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(y = 'Close', ax=ax)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
df3 = df2.pct_change()
df3.plot(y = 'Close', ax=ax2)
```

You will probably need to add a color argument, as both plots will use the same default color.